# How do I specialize type in functional interface's straight declaration?

Tags: java

Recently I came up with idea to create a following method:

```java
/** Returns a {@link Predicate} which tests whether all its elements match a condition passed as argument. */
private static <T> Predicate<Iterable<T>> allIterableElementsMatch(Predicate<T> elementMatchCondition) { 
    return iterable -> stream(iterable).allMatch(elementMatchCondition);
}
```

Then I decided to declare `Function`-field instead of declaring a method above.
The closest **uncompilable** solution I could provide is this one:

```java
private static final Function<Predicate<?>, Predicate<Iterable<?>>> allIterableElementsMatch = 
    condition -> iterable -> stream(iterable).allMatch(condition);
```

This is not compiled (IDE highlights `condition` inside `allMatch(...)`) because of following reason:
[image]

My questions:

1. Is it implementable in that way or I just misunderstand the concept of using functional interfaces?
2. Is it possible to specialize some type in `Function`-s declaration just like in method I've shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the type system, `?` from `Predicate<?>` and `?` from `Predicate<Iterable<?>>` are different things. You can do:

```
private static <T> Function<Predicate<T>, Predicate<Iterable<T>>> func() {
    return condition -> iterable -> StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false).allMatch(condition);
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. The Idea is I would like to declare a field but not the method. Is it possible in your opinion?

Comment: @GromovAnton no it is not, you might want to read more on "wildcard capture" methods...

Comment: as a conclusion, in this case there is no way to tell the compiler that both '?' are related to the same type, am I right?

Comment: @GromovAnton yes, that is correct. it is said that capture conversion happens everywhere